# Unable to find dropdown list element in selenium

Tags: java, select, iframe, selenium

i have written a basic test using selenium. The test is failing as the selenium unable to select the item from drop down list.

My select statement is not getting executed. Also i have include this `select` statement within `iframe` as this falls under it.

Can you please let me know what is the issue with my select statement.

Here is my code for `southwest` website:

```
package Default;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FirstWDWithoutRecording {

@Test
public void SouthWestSignUp() throws InterruptedException
{

    //Open the FF/Chrome browser
    //FirefoxDriver oBrw = new FirefoxDriver();
    ChromeDriver oBrw = new ChromeDriver();

    //Maximize Browser
    oBrw.manage().window().maximize();

    //Open/Launch www.southwest.com
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E://chromedriver.exe");
    oBrw.get("http://www.southwest.com/");

    //Click on Sign up and Save
    //Recognising
    oBrw.findElement(By.linkText("Sign up")).click();

    //oBrw.get("http://www.southwest.com/html/email/click_n_save_signup.html?clk=GFOOTER-CNS-ENROLL");

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    //Enter First Name

    oBrw.switchTo().frame(0);   //'0' as it is the only iframe on the page, the value is the index of all iframes on the page
    //do your login actions

    oBrw.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='FIRST_NAME']")).clear();
    oBrw.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='FIRST_NAME']")).sendKeys("abc");

    //Enter Last Name
    oBrw.findElement(By.id("LAST_NAME")).clear();
    oBrw.findElement(By.id("LAST_NAME")).sendKeys("Kish123");

    //Enter Email ID
    oBrw.findElement(By.id("EMAIL")).clear();
    oBrw.findElement(By.id("EMAIL")).sendKeys("abc@Kish123.com");

    //Selecting Home Airport
    Select uiHomeAp = new Select(oBrw.findElement(By.id("HOME_AIRPORT")));
    uiHomeAp.deselectByVisibleText("Atlanta, GA - ATL");

    //Accepting Conditions
    oBrw.findElement(By.id("IAN")).click();

    //Click Submit
    oBrw.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();

    //after return
    oBrw.switchTo().defaultContent();


     }

 }
```

Comment: **de**selectByVisibleText()? Are you sure you meant de-select and not just select?

Answer (score 0):

As @SiKing had stated, your issue is with your `deselectByVisibleText()`.  You want `selectByVisibleText()`.

```
uiHomeAp.selectByVisibleText("Atlanta, GA - ATL");
```

---

Also wanted to point out that it might be easier if you are just getting started, to check out the [getting started with selenium](http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium-framework) framework.  If you're using maven, you could do:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.ddavison</groupId>
  <artifactId>getting-started-with-selenium-framework</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

then your test would look like this:

```
@Config(browser = Browser.CHROME, url="http://www.southwest.com/")
public class FirstWDWithoutRecording extends AutomationTest {
    public void southWestSignUp() {
        click(By.linkText("Sign up"))
        .switchToFrame(0)
        .setText("input#FIRST_NAME", "abc")
        .setText("input#LAST_NAME", "Kish123")
        .setText("input#EMAIL", "abc@Kish123.com")
        .selectOptionByText("select#HOME_AIRPORT", "Atlanta, GA - ATL")
        .check("#IAN") // check the terms and conditions
        .click("#submit") // form submitted
        .switchToDefaultContent()
        ;
    }
}
```